# Hang rest of paragraph after specific point (or token)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, justification

Say I have some point in a sentence that I want the rest of the paragraph to hang after; result like this:

```
PART / Long title that won't fit on one line that
       we want hanged after the slash on the next line
```

I made this work ish by calculating the width of a box containing the `PART /` prefix, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Prevent extra indent
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
% Box to contain the stuff that the text will hang after
\newbox\partprefixBox
% The stuff that the text will hang after
\def\partprefix{\Large PART /\nobreakspace}
% Set part-header-prefix into the box
\setbox\partprefixBox=\hbox{\partprefix}
\begin{document}
    \bgroup
     % Set the hangindent size (using the box width)
    \hangindent=\wd\partprefixBox%
    \hangafter=1%
    \partprefix Long title that won't fit on one line that we want hanged after the slash on the next line\par
    \egroup
\end{document}
```

I'm wondering if there is a more robust way of doing this, and whether there is a way to do it with centered text (i.e. if the text is not gonna break, then it should be centered).

Ideally something like a `\hanghere` command that would work like so:

```
PART / \hanghere Long title that won't fit on one line that we want hanged after the slash on the next line
```

or this syntax would also work

```
\hanghere{PART / }Long title that won't fit on one line that we want hanged after the slash on the next line
```

and produce the first mentioned result

Any ideas?
Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier with `\hangat{PART} Long title...`

Comment: @egreg that syntax would definitely work!

Comment: If you want to center the thing when it fits a line, then both parts should be passed as arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measure the natural width and decide:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\partlength}

\newcommand{\perhapshang}[2]{%
  \par\noindent
  \sbox0{#1 / #2}%
  \ifdim\wd0<\linewidth
    \makebox[\linewidth]{\usebox0}%
  \else
    \settowidth{\partlength}{#1\mbox{ }/\mbox{ }}%
    \hangafter 1
    \hangindent\partlength
    #1\mbox{ }/\mbox{ }#2
  \fi
  \par
}

\begin{document}

\perhapshang{PART}{Long title that won't fit on one line
  that we want hanged after the slash on the next line}

\perhapshang{PART}{This is short}

\end{document}
```

I use `\mbox{ }` in order to get rigid space.

[image]